# template project in TFS

Tags: visual-studio

I have a "common" web template project in tfs. This web project is mainly for common layout and library framework that will be used for many other projects.
Every time I work on a new project, I always create a branch from the "common" template. With such structure, if there's new changes on the common framework, I can always merge the new changes to the "common" template.

The problem I face now is when I have multiple projects open and I try to run the project, it always run the project I first opened in VS. It think this could be due to the assemblyinfo.cs in the project. I tried to change the solution name and the project name but couldn't resolve the issue.

My VS version is 2012 Professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't find a suitable answer for this. What I had to do to get around is to set the virtual port on the web project.